# after updating react-native to 0.66.1 and xcode to version 13.1, the app stopped running on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios15, xcode13

When launching the application through Xcode, the build is successful. But when installing the application on the device, I get an error.

```
Details

Unable to install "MyHouseReactNativeMigration"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402636802
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
An unknown error message 'ServiceConnectionInterrupted', was received from the device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402636802
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8003FFE)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116dc6316 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116e0484a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ce5dea4 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116e04594 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1420
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000114b0eb4e __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3508
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010cf91c07 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010cf93373 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 931
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff805d07ad8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff805d08cc9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff805d0ecee _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 696
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff805d0f7c8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff805d197e1 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 758
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff805ebc08f _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff805ebb01b start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone10,4";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.1 (19B74)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 7625;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402636802";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
```

System Information

macOS Version 12.0.1 (Build 21A559)
Xcode 13.1 (19466) (Build 13A1030d)
Timestamp: 2021-10-28T14:28:43+03:00

TestFlight also can't install the app...